# Node.js current url - not original

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to get the current url in node js ? I have following code but it doesn't work properly.

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request, response) {
  console.log("Request received.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  console.log(request.headers.host);
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
```

Apache redirecting localhost:3000 to node.dev domain. When I run above code I have: localhost:3000 but I want to node.dev (with subdomain, all url)

Comment: Could you explain how is apache used. Are you using them parallely to host site ?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin davy.brion@thatextramile.be
    ServerName node.dev
    ServerAlias www.node.dev
    ServerAlias profile.node.dev
 
    ProxyRequests off
 
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
 
    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Are you trying to use nodejs as a proxy or apache as proxy, or chaining both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution:

```
request.headers['x-forwarded-host']
```